Serialization Issues?
I create a .NET dataset in my web api that has the following schema when I perform a DataSet.GetXmlSchema:
        <xs:element name="Table2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="PageID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="SystemID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

When I receive the json and deserialize it into a .NET dataset the schema looks like this:
        <xs:element name="Table2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="PageID" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="SystemID" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

It appears that when the DataSet is returned from the Web API it is transforming an INT to a LONG.
What is the best way to fix this?
I tried writing something like this so that when it's deserialized it would convert it back to an INT, but it didn't seem to work.
  public sealed class BasicJsonConverter : JsonConverter
  {
      readonly JsonSerializer defaultSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

      public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(int);

      public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
      {
          switch (reader.TokenType)
          {
              case JsonToken.Integer:
                  if (reader.Value is long longValue && longValue <= int.MaxValue)
                      return Convert.ToInt32(longValue);
                  return reader.Value;
              case JsonToken.Float: // Accepts numbers like 4.00
              case JsonToken.Null:
                  return defaultSerializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
              default:
                  throw new JsonSerializationException($"Token \"{reader.Value}\" of type {reader.TokenType} was not a JSON integer");
          }
      }

      public override bool CanWrite => false;

      public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
      {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
  }

